# import 'react-quill/dist/quill.snow.css' is not working

Tags: reactjs, terminal, quill, react-quill, chokidar

The terminal will no longer display the product and instead says this:-

Failed to compile.

./src/components/Post.js
Module not found: Can't resolve 'react-quill/dist/quill.snow.css' in 'C:\Users\Daksh\OneDrive\Desktop\quora-clone\src\components'
Error from chokidar (C:): Error: EBUSY: resource busy or locked, lstat 'C:\DumpStack.log.tmp'